# C Reading numbers from file and placing them in range bins and printing to file

Tags: c, file-io, range

I'm having an issue with this program.

What I'm trying to do is read lines from the file input.txt, where the first line is the number of integers in the file. input.txt is formatted

5 //num of ints
2
40
49
90
70

Then, I want to print to file output.txt so that output.txt is basically.

range 0-9   1
range 10-19 0
range 20-29 0
range 30-39 0
range 40-49 2
range 50-59 0
range 60-69 0
range 70-79 1
range 80-89 0
range 90-99 1

The ranges will only go up to 99. Thus there is only 10 ranges. So there will never be a number over 99 after the initial line in input.txt.

The issue I'm having is that the program works fine as long as the number of guesses is 10. I know this has to do with how I set the range numbers to increase, since it's tied to the loop. I'm lost on how to do it properly.

Any advice? Thanks, in advance!

What I've got so far:

```
/*

Print a numbers in range to file output.txt from the list of numbers in file input.txt

*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

FILE *input;
FILE *output;

int num_guesses, nums, bin_count=0, guesses_in_bin;
int i, j, k, firstline;
int Bin_Start = 0;
int bin[10];


input= fopen("input.txt", "r");
output= fopen("output.txt", "w");

fprintf(output, "Values        Amounts\n");

fscanf(input, "%d", &num_guesses); //scans first line of input.txt for the number of guesses

for (j=0; j< (num_guesses); j++) //for number of guesses run inside loop

{

    for (i=0; i< (num_guesses); i++)
    {
        fscanf(input, "%d", &nums);
        //printf("            %d\n", nums);
        if (nums >= Bin_Start && nums <= Bin_Start+9) //checks if number belongs in bin.
            bin_count = bin_count+1;






    }
    //rewind
    rewind(input);
    fscanf(input, "%d", &firstline); // used to ignore first line of file


    //reset bin count
    numbers_in_bin = bin_count;
    bin_count = 0;


    fprintf(output, "%2d - %2d      %d", Bin_Start, Bin_Start+9, numbers_in_bin);

    fprintf(output, "\n");

    //Update to next bin

    Bin_Start = Bin_Start+10;




}




fclose(input);
fclose(output);



return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without even looking for more-or-less subtle bugs, stop right here, this solution is already wrong in its concept. The only sane way to solve this is create counters for *all ten possible bins* in advance like:

```
int bin[10] = { 0 };
```

then scan the file *one* time and do something as simple as

```
bin[input/10]++;
```

for output, loop over your bins, eg:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    printf("%d-%d:\t%d\n", 10*i, 10*i+9, bin[i]);
}
```